# Is HLS different to DASH-MPEG because of the video file type?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, mpeg-dash, media-source

Hope someone doesn't mind this question because it's not a 'coding' based question.

I'm creating a HTML5 Video Player which is able to switch video, audio and subtitles. I have created a video player using the Media Source Extension API. But my video player does not work on an IOS Device (iPhone 6s Plus with Latest IOS update) through all web browsers (Safari, Chrome etc). I saw that the Media Source Extension API is not compatible with IOS devices (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). I researched and found that IOS Devices can only play web video via the HLS Method. I also found that HLS is using Media Source Extension API, therefor why is my Media Source Extension created video player not working.

So through this I fully don't understand to why is my media player not working. I'm assuming that the problem is related with the file type compatibility. My created video player is using `MP4` video file type. While the HLS or IOS Devices uses `m3u8` and uses `.ts` segments.

Please help me in understanding the compatibility problem I'm facing. So overall I just want to know why my Media Source Extension created video player is not working. Is it because the of file types? Or another reason?

If the question was not understood properly... please comment below.

`HLS Demo` : https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/

`Media Source Extension API Demo` <- `doesn't work on IOS device` : http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferAll.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HLS can use fMP4, or TS. Yes it requires an m3u8 manifest. No iOS does not support media source extensions. MSE can only play fMP4.

Comment: It is said that HLS uses MSE. If iOS doesn't support MSE then how is HLS working? Can you just clarify this for me?

Comment: Because iOS has explicit support for HLS in the video tag (as does safari and edge). Other browsers do not, so supported must be added to the  browser via player software.